# how to access report filters, programatically

Tags: apex, reporting

I know you can access the data in a report's DATA programtically, but how do I access the **filters**?

Basically, I want to transform the report into a soql query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only access the report definition via the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/). The [Report](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_report.htm) component type shown here contains the information you need.

This is a Web Service API and not native to Apex. However if you your willing to try it you can use this [library](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) built around it to access it from Apex. I've included a demo of it below showing it retrieving a Report definition on a Visualforce page.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact solution you are looking for, we can do like this:

```
// Get the report ID
List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where 
    DeveloperName = 'Company_owned_Independent_sites'];
String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

 // Run a report
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);

// Get the report metadata
Reports.ReportMetadata rm = results.getReportMetadata();
for(Reports.ReportFilter rf : rm.getreportFilters()){
    system.debug('---col name---'+rf.getcolumn());
    system.debug('---col value---'+rf.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the force.com explorer to browse the data and create soql queries.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

- Not sure of your needs, but with this tool, you can create the report/soql query you need.

Comment: Wrong (recursive) link? And I'd suspect author already knows how to write & test SOQL with a tool of his choice ;)

Comment: fixed the link. As for the tool: maybe.